# Vue.js is not working when script is loaded before html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue.js. I found that the binding is not working when the javascript is loaded before the html template.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var demo = new Vue({
   el: '#demo',
   data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
   },
   methods: {
    speak: function() {alert(this.message);}
   }
  })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="demo">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
  <button v-on:click.prevent='speak'>speak</button>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, it works when the script is placed after the html template that the vue.js script is bound to.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="demo">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
  <button v-on:click.prevent='speak'>speak</button>
 </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
  message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
  speak: function() {alert(this.message);}
  }
 })
</script>
</html>
```

I guess this problem is analogous to whether to put the code in ready() when using jQuery. I have searched in google about ready() of Vue.js but it is inside the Vue.js instance. Is there a ready() function just like that of jQuery so that I can load the script before the html? Or, must I Vue.js load the script after the html template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `window.onload` for this task.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // your code here
}
```

Or you can register a function to `load` event :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // your code here
})
```